# git diff to find refactor name changes in c

Tags: c, git, refactoring

Recently a large refactor of our C code occured on our code base.  I wanted to come up with a quick list of changed structure / function call names using git.  Below is how I did this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use git to find whole word differences, rather than line differences

   ```
   git diff dev --word-diff-regex="([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"
   ```
2. Pipe this through sed to find clean up the output.
   You will get output like

   [-OldName-]{+NewName+}
3. Build a regex to output OldName NewName

   ```
   sed -n "s/.*\[-\([a-zA-Z_]*\)-\]{+\([a-zA-Z_0-9]*\)+}.*/\1 \2/p"
   ```
4. Combine this with uniq, and sort for a inital list of changed names.

   ```
   git diff dev --word-diff-regex="([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)" | \\  
   sed -n "s/.*\[-\([a-zA-Z_]*\)-\]{+\([a-zA-Z_0-9]*\)+}.*/\1 \2/p" | \\  
   sort | \\  
   uniq
   ```